# Prometheus metric comparison alert

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm trying to create an alert expression that fires if the given metric is not the same across all targets. Let's call my metric `my_gauge` where the expression console output shows:

```
my_gauge{group="test",instance="huey:9100",job="example"}   10
my_gauge{group="test",instance="duey:9100",job="example"}   10
my_gauge{group="test",instance="luey:9100",job="example"}   7
```

I'm interested in the target results that are below the highest threshold. So my initial thought was to compare it to the `max (my_gauge)` result which is:

```
{} 10
```

However `my_gauge < max(my_gauge)` returns `no data` (the expected result here would be luey). How do I write an expression that would return a target with a divergent metric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to alert on wether at least one value is different, you can compare if minimum value is the same as maximum value:

```
expr: min(my_gauge) by(group) != max(my_gauge) by(group)
```

If you want to alert on every value that differs, you can use the median to determine the common value (10 in your example). And then compare to it.

```
expr: my_gauge != on(group) group_left quantile(0.5, my_gauge) by(group)
```

Regarding your expression, you are missing the [vector matches](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches):

```
expr: my_gauge < on() group_left max(my_gauge)
```